# After submit the merchant details - {"curlError":"unable to set private key file: 'applepay.key.pem' type PEM"}

Tags: php, private-key, php-curl, pem, applepay

I try to integrate the Apple pay in website using php,
After submit the merchant details (crt.pem,key.pem,keycertificate password.) in apple server, it will throwing the below error
"unable to set private key file: ApplePay.key.pem"
Can anyone help please

We have tried creating pem files in various command code
but no luck